# Emit Livewire event and listen in Vue component

Tags: vue.js, events, laravel-livewire, listen

Is there a way to execute an event in **Livewire** component and listen about it in the **Vue** component?

Or emitting browser event from **Livewire** with `$this->dispatchBrowserEvent('event-name');` and listen about it in the **Vue** component?

**Is this kind of communication achievable at all?**

Please any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can checkout [livewire/vue](https://github.com/livewire/vue) github page.

From there you can follow [Dispatching Browser Events](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events) docs.